# What does "whisper thin" mean?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, books

This phrase is from [*Out to Get You: 13 Tales of Weirdness and Woe*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dH7RDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT16&lpg=PT16&dq=The+cat+was+whisper+thin+and+had+a+notch+in+its+ear.&source=bl&ots=O7SaGDWnzF&sig=ACfU3U2_Y1DU6nVeBxvS20NZ7A4LRh02vw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-wfCij6TpAhWUtXEKHVbQBkIQ6AEwEnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=The%20cat%20was%20whisper%20thin%20and%20had%20a%20notch%20in%20its%20ear.&f=false) by Josh Allen (2019) and I'm not sure what it means by *whisper thin*.

> The cat was **whisper thin** and had a notch in its ear.

Comment: A whisper is a sound you can hardly hear because it is so quiet; a whisper thin cat could be one you can hardly see because it is so thin. Also it sounds like 'wisp'.

Comment: But it was a cat! It’s just begging for ***whisker thin***...

Answer (score 1):

The phrase seems to come more from the verb "to thin":

OED

> **1 To make thin; to reduce in thickness or depth;**
>
> 1793   Trans. Soc. Arts (ed. 2) 5 204   The two ends are to be thinned off in form of a wedge.

and from The Freedictionary: we have "thin"(adjective) being "dilute" or "to dilute"

> 2020  Broth - A **thin**, clear soup based on stock, to which rice, barley, meat, or vegetables may be added.

2020 Greybeard EL&U "He added turpentine in order to **thin** the paint."

Thus we see that a soup is thicker than a broth.

"To thin" was then used figuratively in the sense of reduce or dilute.

> 1787   T. Jefferson Writings (1859) II. 117   Real friends, whose affections are not thinned to cob-web.

Sir A. C. Doyle in "Round the Red Lamp" writes:

> "It was then I learned that [...] that rough voice could **thin** into a whisper when it spoke to a sick child.

Thus we have **whisper thin** = *as thin as a whisper* = as weak and diluted (in sound) as a whisper (which is "thin").

So now we have whisper being used figuratively to mean "thin", and "thin" being literal so "the cat was whisper thin" = "the cat was thin thin = "the cat was very thin indeed.